# How to make an image a link when screen becomes small

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a web page to learn about responsive web development and have run into a problem with my links.  When the page width is small I would like to add hyperlinks to my images however when it becomes large I would like to take them off the images and put them on another element.  Is there a way to do this with HTML, CSS and/or JavaScript?

For more context please take a look at [this](http://www.hangrylemur.com) slideshow where I have added a breakpoint at screen width 450px.  When the screen is wider, the hyperlink is on the "Read More" button, however I would like it to be on the image when the "Read More" button disappears.

Comment: You could use CSS media queries to handle this.  You could have a parent div which contains an image and link attribute.  At some breakpoint (width) you could hide the element that contains the link and then show it again once you reach some other specified breakpoint.  Using Javascript sounds overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use jQuery, you could do something like this:

[Demo](http://codepen.io/medinasod/pen/rxYRpd)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  moveLink();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  moveLink();
});

function moveLink() {  
  if ($(window).width() >= 450) {
    $("#myImage").unwrap();
    $("#myText").wrap('<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">').show();
  } else {
    $("#myText").unwrap().hide();
    $("#myImage").wrap('<a id="myLink" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com"></a>');
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="myImage" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
<br>

  <span id="myText">Read More</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Example using media queries (minimize the window to be less than 600px, you will see the link, otherwise you will see the image):

https://jsfiddle.net/89ptv9mt/

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .logo {
      display : none;
    }
    .altText {
      display : block;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
    .logo{
        display : block;
    }
  .altText {
      display : none;
    }
}

<img class="logo" src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png" alt="MDN">
<a href="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png" class="altText">MDN</a>
```